# awk variable inside a shell function

Tags: bash, shell, variables, awk

I wrote a shell function as below

```
extract () {        
    awk -vbegin="${1}" '/begin/ {flag=1;next} /=====/{flag=0} flag {
        print
    }   
    ' "$2" | egrep "$3" | egrep -v "$4"
}
```

However, when I call

```
extract "Begin Criteria" "First" "Second" "Third1|Third2"
```

The 1st variable "Begin Criteria" seems could not be parsed at /begin/

How could I make my call similar to?

```
awk '/Begin Criteria/ {flag=1;next} /=====/{flag=0} flag {
        print
}
' First | egrep 'Second' | egrep -v 'Third1|Third2'
```

Raw_data_file

```
First Bundle ====
    First 1       
        Second 1
            Third_1 1
            Third_2 1
=====

Second Bundle ====
    Second 1   
        Third_1 1
        Third_2 1
        Third_3 1
=====

Third Bundle ====
    Third_1 1  
    Third_2 1 
    Third_3 1
=====

First Bundle ====
    First 2           
        Second 2
            Third_1 2
            Third_2 2
=====

Second Bundle ====
    Second 2   
        Third_1 2
        Third_2 2
        Third_3 2
=====

Third Bundle ====
    Third_1 2   
    Third_2 2
    Third_3 2
=====
```

Usage

```
extract "Second Bundle" Raw_data_file "Second" "Third1|Third2" Second.out
extract "Third Bundle" Raw_data_file "Third1|Third2" "" Third.out
extract "First Bundle" Raw_data_file "" "" First.out
```

Expected

First.out

```
First 1       
    Second 1
        Third_1 1
        Third_2 1
First 2       
    Second 2
        Third_1 2
        Third_2 2
```

Second.out

```
Second 1   
Second 2
```

Third.out

```
Third_1 1   
Third_2 1   
Third_1 2   
Third_2 2
```

Comment: You are using `awk` and then two `egrep`s. Probably `awk` suffices to do this alone. Also, post some sample input and desired output to make it more clear. Finally, `flag { print }` is not necessary; with `flag` alone you get the same result.

Comment: input and output post. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use variable in awk you can do:

```
awk -vbegin="${1}" '$0 ~ begin {flag=1;next} /=====/{flag=0} flag {
        print
}'
```

When you use `/begin/` you're literally matching text `begin` not the variable `begin`.

Answer (score 0):

You never needs pipes to/from grep, etc. when you are using awk since awk can do anything useful that grep can do. Rewrite your function as:

```
extract () {        
    awk -v begin="$1" -v plus="$3" -v minus="$4" '
        /=====/ {flag=0}
        flag && ($0 ~ plus) && ($0 !~ minus)
        $0 ~ begin {flag=1}
    ' "$2"
}
```

Untested since you didn't provide any sample input or expected output.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I updated my question, added sample input and expected result. Your suggest solution works fine if we only have single "minus"/"plus"